# Integrate Cocos2dx project within Swift Project (XCode 6.3)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocos2d-x-3.0, xcode6.3

I have 2 separate Projects one is in Cocos2dx v3.6 and one is in Swift.
I want to start a game from the Swift project.
How can I do it?

I have copied whole cocos2dx project into my Swift project and then created one View Controller in swift and trying to open CCDirector as a root view of the project. but not able to find director, I am trying to import cocos2dx with this **#import "cocos2d.h"**
, but it is giving me error of "undefined file".

[image: This is how I added Cocos2dx project in my Swift Project]

Apple Swift version 1.2

Comment: Are you adding C++ to a Swift project?

Comment: I am done with this integration using , bridging of Swift and Objective C and made a simple class when I can push CCDirector to the current navigation controller and one method from Cocos2dx class calls Objective C class and objective C class calls back the Swift method to Pop the view controller

Comment: I will Soon, post the details regarding what I did to make these bridging classes and how it all worked for me.

Comment: @Anand how you did that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use version Cocos2d for Swift it is here. [this](https://github.com/chunkyguy/Cocos2dSwift)

Also I suggest you use this [tutorial](http://whackylabs.com/rants/?p=1053) it is very simple todo.